Bun, Remix, Vite and NX, Resolving Import issues with @lingui/macro - Named export 'createMacro' not found
Thanks to itxch from GitHub, I'm integrating Vite, Remix, and NX.
I'm receiving the following error:
Error when evaluating SSR module /@fs/Users/joseasilis/Documents/programming/alertdown/nx/nx-remix-vite/libs/ui/src/templates/AuthForm/index.tsx: failed to import "@lingui/macro"
|- file:///Users/joseasilis/Documents/programming/alertdown/nx/nx-remix-vite/node_modules/@lingui/macro/dist/index.mjs:1
import { createMacro } from 'babel-plugin-macros';
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Named export 'createMacro' not found. The requested module 'babel-plugin-macros' is a CommonJS module, which may not support all module.exports as named exports.
CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:

import pkg from 'babel-plugin-macros';
const { createMacro } = pkg;

I've tried manually going to the index.js file in node_modules, and destructure  it to commonjs:
const { createMacro } from 'babel-plugin-macros';

That didn't work.
Here's my vite.config.ts file:
/// <reference types='vitest' />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { nxViteTsPaths } from '@nx/vite/plugins/nx-tsconfig-paths.plugin';
import { vitePlugin as remix } from '@remix-run/dev';
import { expressDevServer } from 'remix-express-dev-server';
import { denyImports } from 'vite-env-only';
import { lingui } from '@lingui/vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
export default defineConfig({
  root: __dirname,
  cacheDir: '../../node_modules/.vite/apps/alertdown-vite',
  plugins: [
    expressDevServer(),
    denyImports({}),
    remix(),
    lingui({
      // This is needed for lingui to pickup the config
      cwd: __dirname,
    }),
    nxViteTsPaths(),
  ],

  test: {
    setupFiles: ['test-setup.ts'],
    watch: false,
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    include: ['./tests/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}'],
    reporters: ['default'],
    coverage: {
      reportsDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/alertdown',
      provider: 'v8',
    },
  },
});

My root package.json
{
  "name": "@alertdown/source",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nx dev @alertdown/app",
    "gen": "nx g @nx/js:lib",
    "reset": "nx reset"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@analytics/segment": "^2.1.0",
    "@lingui/core": "^4.12.0",
    "@lingui/macro": "^4.12.0",
    "@nx/remix": "20.0.0",
    "@remix-run/node": "^2.12.1",
    "@remix-run/react": "^2.12.1",
    "@remix-run/serve": "^2.12.1",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "isbot": "^5.1.17",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "remix-create-express-app": "^0.4.5",
    "remix-express-dev-server": "^0.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@eslint/js": "^9.8.0",
    "@lingui/cli": "^4.12.0",
    "@lingui/vite-plugin": "^4.12.0",
    "@nx/devkit": "20.0.0",
    "@nx/eslint": "20.0.0",
    "@nx/eslint-plugin": "20.0.0",
    "@nx/js": "20.0.0",
    "@nx/playwright": "20.0.0",
    "@nx/vite": "20.0.0",
    "@nx/web": "20.0.0",
    "@nx/workspace": "20.0.0",
    "@playwright/test": "^1.47.2",
    "@remix-run/dev": "^2.12.1",
    "@remix-run/testing": "^2.12.1",
    "@swc-node/register": "~1.10.9",
    "@swc/core": "~1.7.26",
    "@swc/helpers": "~0.5.11",
    "@testing-library/react": "^16.0.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.5.2",
    "@types/node": "18.16.9",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.3.2",
    "@vitest/coverage-v8": "^2.1.2",
    "@vitest/ui": "^2.1.2",
    "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint": "^9.8.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-playwright": "^1.6.2",
    "nx": "20.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.3.3",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.13",
    "tslib": "^2.7.0",
    "typescript": "~5.6.2",
    "typescript-eslint": "^8.0.0",
    "vite": "^5.4.8",
    "vite-env-only": "^3.0.3",
    "vitest": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "volta": {
    "node": "20.18.0"
  }
}

Any ideas?

Albeit counterintuitive, the solution was to add the react's plugin macro even though Remix doesn't need it.
 react({
      babel: {
        plugins: ['macros'],
      },
    }),

/// <reference types='vitest' />
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import { nxViteTsPaths } from '@nx/vite/plugins/nx-tsconfig-paths.plugin';
import { vitePlugin as remix } from '@remix-run/dev';
import { expressDevServer } from 'remix-express-dev-server';
import { denyImports } from 'vite-env-only';
import { lingui } from '@lingui/vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
export default defineConfig({
  root: __dirname,
  cacheDir: '../../node_modules/.vite/apps/alertdown-vite',
  plugins: [
    expressDevServer(),
    denyImports({}),
    remix(),
    react({
      babel: {
        plugins: ['macros'],
      },
    }),
    lingui({
      cwd: __dirname,
    }),
    nxViteTsPaths(),
  ],

  test: {
    setupFiles: ['test-setup.ts'],
    watch: false,
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
    include: ['./tests/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}'],
    reporters: ['default'],
    coverage: {
      reportsDirectory: '../../coverage/apps/alertdown',
      provider: 'v8',
    },
  },
});

Additionally, be sure to include the cwd: __dirname, for the lingui plugin or it won't work.
